# Why do values not appear in ecdf plot?

Tags: debugging, r, statistics

I am trying to plot the ccdf of the data given below but for some reason, it doesn't look right. I was cross checking with some data points (2523, 313, 224) but they are not visible. Am I doing something wrong?

**R Script:**

```
# Y defined below
Y.ecdf = ecdf(Y)
curve((length((Y))*(1-Y.ecdf(x))), n = 10000, 
       from = 0, to = 100, xlab = "# of items", 
       ylab = "# instances", col=colors[1], lty=1, lwd=4)
```

[image: ecdf plot]

```
Y = c( 3, 1, 4, 11, 2, 2, 9, 7, 22, 3, 1, 1, 7, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 6, 3, 20,
15, 4, 1, 1, 5, 3, 10, 16, 224, 74, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 9,
3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2,
2, 1, 1, 5, 6, 13, 15, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4,
2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3,
2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1,
4, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3,
2, 3, 9, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 22, 5, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 31, 1, 1,
2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 8, 6, 6, 7, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 1, 2, 6, 6, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2,
1, 5, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 212, 2,
7, 7, 10, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 16, 6, 2, 10, 2, 1, 1, 15, 1, 3, 8,
1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 9, 4, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4, 9,
6, 19, 1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 6, 9, 5, 11, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 313, 3, 1, 3, 1,
2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 5, 1, 20, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5,
4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 13, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,
2, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2523, 7, 4, 2, 4, 11, 8, 1, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 3,
1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 2, 2, 1, 8, 8, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2,
6, 2, 2, 2, 1, 5, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 10, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2,
2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 96, 2, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2,
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 10, 3, 2, 2, 8, 8, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 13, 20, 3, 2,
5, 9, 1, 22, 25, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 7, 9, 5, 9, 1, 3, 1, 8, 2, 2, 1, 3,
1, 2, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 16, 3, 5, 2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The `from` and `to` arguments in `curve` tell it to only plot between those  values. Why would you expect to see values larger than 100 on the resulting graph?

Comment: @joran: But this 2000 point in my dataset should appear on my Y-axis isn't it?

Comment: No. I think you're a little confused about what an [ecdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) should look like. What you're plotting is actually an inverted, scaled transformation of an ecdf. The range of values in your data goes on the x axis and the 'cumulative proportion' of you data goes on the y axis.

Comment: Try just calling `plot(Y.ecdf)`. That will produce the actual ecdf plot, showing all the values. It's a little ugly, though, since you have such huge outliers.

Comment: @joran: +1 Ah... You're right! My bad! That `from` and `to` really had be confused. In that case, removing `from` and `to` should do the trick right? I am trying to focus on the tail so would you recommend a good way of doing this? Do I just scale the y-axis to examine the tail?

Comment: Added an answer rather than a comment. It's probably overkill, but I figured it might help other people who stumble across this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on our discussion in the comments...

An empirical cumulative distribution function is a plot of X (x axis) vs. Pr(X < x) (y axis). So for your example it would look something like this:

```
plot(Y.ecdf,do.points = FALSE,
     verticals = TRUE,col = "blue",
     xlab = "x", ylab = "Pr(X < x)")
```

[image]

If you look very closely you can see where the line goes up when you reach your very large values, but it's hard to make out since so many of your values are less than 10.

What you've done is to invert this function so that you're looking at the opposite tail of the distribution, i.e. Pr(X > x). You've also scaled the probabilities on the y axis. I'm not sure why, but whatever. It might make sense given your particular task. So you're doing something like this (but with the y axis scaling):

```
curve((1-Y.ecdf(x)), n = 10000, 
       from = 0, to = 2600, ylab = "Pr(X > x)", 
       xlab = "x", col="blue", lty=1, lwd=2)
```

[image]

but you originally had the `from` and `to` arguments set to only plot the function from 0 to 100. If you wanted to "zoom in" on your outliers, you could just change the `from` and `to` values to something more relevant:

```
curve((1-Y.ecdf(x)), n = 10000, 
       from = 250, to = 2600, ylab = "Pr(X > x)", 
       xlab = "x", col="blue", lty=1, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Another way to expand the tail region is to plot the log of the probability (either Pr(X > x) or Pr(X < x)).

Comment: @BrianDiggs Facepalm! SO has me thinking too much like a programmer and not enough like a statistician.

Comment: +1 Wonderful! Thank you so much for your time in helping me understand this. @BrianDiggs: Thanks to you too :)